# OrCAD PCB Designer File Export to PDF (Gerber)

Tags: pcb, orcad, allegro

[image]

i want to export this PCB circuit to PDF exacty as it is (above image), but when i click on file -> export -> PDF, its shows exacty the window on the left "Allegro PDF Publisher", then i click on film creation, and the window on the right pop up, i custumized the domain to SMBOTTOM, to show only the pin soldermask bottom, pin/bottom, etch/bottom and board geometry outline all with black color, exacty as the first image, but the PDF exported (last image) is different than the first image (like i want).

My question is how do i export the first image to PDF exacty as it is ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Answer below, however this question name is mis-leading. It has nothing to do with PSPICE. PSPICE is the simulation software. Allegro / OrCAD PCB are the PCB layout tools. I notice you have done similar things in previous questions also.

Comment: the PDF is enabled on SMBOTTOM (sorry i didn't update the image on the right), SMBottom already appear and the result is on the last image, i still can't figure out how to print exacty on first image, maybe i try to copy paste to MS Word, and check the dimensions.

Comment: Is the main problem between the two pictures that the holes aren't shown? Or what is/are the critical difference(s) between them that you are trying to fix?

Comment: Obviously the 1st image also has the toolbars, but I'm guessing these aren't relevant to your question... Let us know.

Comment: Yes the main problem between the two pictures is that the holes aren't shown as white, also the other problem is all the pins aren't completly black.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on "Domain Selection" in the "Film Control" window
[image: film control]

Make sure the "PDF" option is enabled for SMBottom.
[image: domain selection]

Then it will appear.